# SQL Query for midnight transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, time

What query do I use to get transactions including midnight (past midnight). For instance:

On 1st January 2018

Our Department Stores opens daily from 7am until 2am(next day)
So 2am transactions as seen as the sale for '1 January 2018'

**This is my Query**

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-02'
and Time >= '1754-01-01 07:00:00.000' and Time <='1754-01-01 01:59:00.000'
```

Currently my query only takes transactions until 11:59:59
But our store opens past midnight,
I want to get transaction everyday until 2am

Comment: Please specify your datatype of Date and Time column

Comment: If you're storing date and time for the same events, please store them *as* a `datetime2` and not as two separate columns.

Comment: Date and Time columns are of type "Data Type"

Comment: @Sequel3 - respectfully, no. If you are not the database administrator for this system, ask them what data types these two columns are. `Data` is not a proper data type in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should combine the Date and Time column inside a single DATETIME column. Having said that, the following should work:

```
WITH testdata(Date, Time) AS (
    SELECT '2018-01-01', '1754-01-01 06:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-01', '1754-01-01 07:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-01', '1754-01-01 08:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-01', '1754-01-01 23:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-02', '1754-01-01 00:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-02', '1754-01-01 01:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-02', '1754-01-01 06:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-02', '1754-01-01 07:00:00' UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-02', '1754-01-01 08:00:00' UNION
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS DATE), CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) -- type cast
)
SELECT *
FROM testdata
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-02'
AND (
    Date = '2018-01-01' AND Time >= '1754-01-01 07:00:00' OR 
    Date = '2018-01-02' AND Time <  '1754-01-01 07:00:00'
)
```

For completeness, I am including any transaction before 7:00 AM to previous day. Result:

```
| Date       | Time                    |
|------------|-------------------------|
| 2018-01-01 | 1754-01-01 07:00:00.000 |
| 2018-01-01 | 1754-01-01 08:00:00.000 |
| 2018-01-01 | 1754-01-01 23:00:00.000 |
| 2018-01-02 | 1754-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-01-02 | 1754-01-01 01:00:00.000 |
| 2018-01-02 | 1754-01-01 06:00:00.000 |
```

Comment: Thanks,what If I seperate date and time columns?Date column comes as 2 blocks,1 block for the Date and the other block for the time.If so,how do i modify my query

Comment: The above query assumes that date and time are stored in separate column. Let me know if there is something you do not understand.

Comment: This query is a bit advanced,however My date columns has time so does my time column.Example of Date : 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 | Example of Time : 1754-01-01 21:32:38.477.How Can i run my Query?

Comment: I believe you simply have to remove the `WITH (...)` part and replace testdata with your table name :) For any date, replace `2018-01-01` and `2018-01-02` with that date and that date + 1 day. I assume that time columns always begins with `1754-01-01` and the date column always ends with `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

if date column has time then just use

```
WHERE Date>='2018-01-01 07:00:00.000' AND Date<='2018-01-02 01:59:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get transactions for the given day, you could declare the date in a variable and then have the query search for records that are between (@date + 7 hours: 7 am) and (@date + 26 hours: 2 am the next day), which you can do by using the dateadd function. For simplicity, I've declared the startdate and enddate in variables as well.

```
Declare @date datetime = '2018-01-01';
Declare @startdate datetime = dateadd(hour, 7, @date);
Declare @enddate datetime = dateadd(hour, 26, @date);

select * 
from table
WHERE Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

This will only work if your date column is of datetime datatype, though.

If you're storing your date and time in separate columns, you can combine them. Like so:

```
Declare @date datetime = '2018-01-01';
Declare @startdate datetime = dateadd(hour, 7, @date);
Declare @enddate datetime = dateadd(hour, 26, @date);

select * 
from table
WHERE (cast(date as datetime) + cast(cast(time as time) as datetime)) 
BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Comment: If I use Declare in the start,will all my records change in the table to the "declared date"?

Comment: No, they won’t. The variable is completely separate from the data in your table. The query just compares the dates in your table to the date range of X + 7 hours and X + 26 hours. In this instance, it will see if the date is between 7 am, 01/01/2018 and 2 am 02/01/2018.

Answer (score 0):

As your day is offset by 2 hours into the following day, I would just pull your date back by 2 hours.

Here is some example / test code.  The select subtracts 2 hours from the input @testdate datetime and then truncates it to the day, chopping off the hours

```
declare @testdate as datetime = '2018-01-01 10:15'
select cast(dateadd(hour,-2,@testdate) as date)

set @testdate = '2018-01-02 01:15'
select cast(dateadd(hour,-2,@testdate) as date)
```

Both select statements return

```
2018-01-01
```

If you store date and time separately additionally run the following sql to combine them

```
cast(Date as datetime) + cast(Time as datetime)
```

e.g

```
select cast(dateadd(hour,-2,cast(Date as datetime) + cast(Time as datetime)) as date)
```